# Why can't I capture mouse in constructor

Tags: wpf, constructor, mouse, capture, shapes

I have custom shape deriving from shape. Inside the constructor I want to capture the mouse, I cannot, I can only capture it once the shape has been created, does any one know why, I would like to capture it inside the constructor?

Comment: Where exactly (in Window constructor, in the UserControl constructor etc.) are you trying to capture the mouse? And why do you need the mouse data there?

Comment: When I create the shape, I want to capture the mouse, so that when the user drags the mouse I can set the shape data (such as path geometry), I do not want to do this in the canvas, that is I do not want the use of my shape to rely on registering a mouse move on the canvas and adjusting the shape path data in there, I would rather do it in the shape class. So instead of relying on the user to capture the mouse on the shape when it is created I wanted to do it in the constructor of the shape.

Answer (score 0):

If you need to create different Shapes depending upon the position or movement of the mouse cursor I would use the appropriate events of your Window or parent container to gather this information (e.g. to "capture" your mouse) and pass this information directly to the constructor or call an appropriate constructor of a certain subclass depending upon this information. 
There is no need to capture this info in constructor then.